# Is there any formula to find trailing zeros?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What $3$-digit number would result in the most significant number of trailing zeros when we multiply it by $320$?

Comment: "Most significant"? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon factoring $320$, one can see $320=2^{5}\cdot10$. To maximize the `significant number of trailing zeros`, I would first attempt to multiply by $5$ as many times as the number of factor $2$ occurs in $320$, since $2\cdot5=10$.

Since the question is asking for a 3-digit number, the most one can achieve is $625=5^{4}$. I believe that $625$ is the answer, since $320\cdot625=200000$.